# Variance of sample mean in an AR(1) process

Tags: time-series

I learned that for an AR(1) model $x_n = b + \phi x_{n-1} + a_n$ with $|\phi| < 1$ and $a_n \sim WN(0, \sigma_a^2)$, the covariance between $x_n$ and $x_{n+h}$  is
$$
\mathrm{Cov} (h)
= \frac{\sigma_a^2 \phi^h}{1 - \phi^2}$$

Now I would like compute the variance of the sample mean
$$
\mathrm{Var}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}
= \frac{n \mathrm{Cov}(0) + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 2(n-i) \mathrm{Cov}(i)}
{n^2}  
= \frac{\sigma_a^2}{(1 - \phi^2) n^2} 
[n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 2(n-i) \phi^i]
$$

Can it be simplified further? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 2(n-i) \phi^i=
2\phi^{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (n-i) \left(\frac 1\phi\right)^{n-i-1}\\
=2\phi^{n-1} \frac d{dx} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x^{n-i}|_{x=1/\phi}
\\
=2\phi^{n-1} \frac{(n-1)\phi^{-(n+1)} - n\phi^{-n} + \phi^{-1}}
{\phi^{-1}(\phi^{-1}-1)^2}\\=
2 \frac{(n-1)\phi^{-1} - n + \phi^{n-1}}
{(\phi^{-1}-1)^2}
$$yields
$$
\mathrm{Var}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}=
\frac{\sigma_a^2}{(1 - \phi^2) n^2} 
\left[
n + 2 \frac{(n-1)\phi^{-1} - n + \phi^{n-1}}
{(\phi^{-1}-1)^2}
\right]
$$

Comment: Thanks! Is there a time series book on this?

Comment: what do you call 'this'? I used just a few computation tricks, I did not know the result before. For a general reference I use the book related to [this site](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/nltsa/), because my teacher is one of the authors.