# Is sample variance of identical but correlated variables a consistent estimator for true variance?

Tags: time-series, correlation, consistency

We know that sample mean and sample variance for iid random variables is a consistent estimator for true mean and true variance, but how about if the random variables follows same distribution but correlated?

I can show that the sample mean is still consistent, but how about the sample variance of identical but correlated variables? Is a consistent estimator for true variance?

Anyone has idea how to prove this ?

Thanks

Comment: "I can show that the sample mean is still consistent"---clearly is not true. Take the trivial case where correlation is one. Same for variance.

Comment: Not in general (unless the specific pattern of correlations is fortuitously just as needed to make it work out). For an example, consider the variance of an AR(1) process -- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90062/variance-of-sample-mean-in-an-ar1-process